# Citing multiple Github repositories with a single citation

Tags: citations

I have reached the maximum paper length and already shortened everything as possible. I use 4 different github repositories, which I mention in my paper. Unfortunately, there is absolutely no room left to add a citation for each repository.

What options are there to solve this problem?

Would it be a good idea to create a new own repository that references the 4 different repositories and only cite my own repository?

Comment: Are the repositories your work, or the work of others?

Comment: All repositories are of different people

Comment: Are you sure references are included in the maximum length? For many conferences references are excluded from the page count, precisely to avoid authors removing relevant references.

Comment: Unfortunately, references were added to the page limit. I've added the github links as a footnote. So they are still in the paper, but do not take up so much space.

Comment: How much are you over? Perhaps you can ask the editors for a nominal break on the word limit (e.g., "I've cut as much as I can, can I exceed the word limit by 42 words?")

Comment: Rather than footnotes, it's also possible (and in my field, permissible), to just give the URL in the text. That's usually way more space-efficient than a footnote.

Answer (score 1):

There are really only two solutions to this problem, and which is appropriate depends on the customs of your field:

1. Name the repositories (and possibly give their URLs), but do not formally cite them. In some fields this will be unacceptable, others it's up to the author, and in yet while others it is considered unacceptable to cite a non-peer-reviewed source like a repository (I have had journals force me to de-formalize software citations before!).
2. Shrink something else to make space for the repository citations. You may think this is not possible, but I promise you that you can get the few lines you need without significantly affecting content through minor tweaks in wording, layout, and such (including in reference contents!)

Answer (score -1):

You could create a DOI for each repository with [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/) and then put all the DOI's in a single reference. Note that you can connect your github account to Zenodo, making the whole procedure really straightforward (see [here](https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/) for a how-to).

Not very elegant, but I don't see any other "simple" solution.

Answer (score -2):

URLs (including those for Github repositories) needn't be cited, they can (and commonly should) be included as footnotes.

Comment: Strongly disagree.  References are references, and all references should be cited.

Comment: Agree with @JeffE and remember that if someone needs to cite a repository, then it means they actually used the work in their own research.

Comment: On the other hand, this is typical in my field.